# .getText() method waits for timeout (implicitlyWait) even if the item is available in DOM and is displayed

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am taking data from a cell in a table.
Everything works, but because of the timeout issue, I have a slow method speed.
This timeout is set when the driver is declared.
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(7));
The app runs randomly slow, so I need this value to be at least 7 seconds.

If I try to get a text from a web element, it takes X seconds to do so (X = implicitlyWait) despite the text is visible and can be found in the DOM as soon as the page is loaded (instantly).
List cells = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//someXpath"));
String result = cells.get(0).getText();

But if I try to get a value from an input field- it doesn't wait. It's worth noting that both the input field and the text in the div (for the first example) are available in DOM instantly.
String result = cells.get(0).findElement(By.xpath(".//input")).getAttribute("value");

This only happens with .getText() method calls in some parts of my code. In other parts of the code it works fine.
For example, in this case I call the method from the IF statement that is inside the FOR loop. However, getAttribute("value") is in the same place.

So the question is why does the .getText() method wait for this implicitlyWait timeout if the text is available?
For example, if I set the timeout to 1000 seconds, I will receive the text after 1000 seconds.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(Hooks.currentDateTime() + "  ---  check cell");
            List<WebElement> cells = rows.get(i).findElements(cellsRelativeXpath);
            List<WebElement> inputElementsInSearchedColumn  = cells.get(searchHeaderIndex).findElements(By.xpath(".//input"));
            int numberOfInputElements = inputElementsInSearchedColumn.size();
            if (cells.get(criteriaHeaderIndex).getText().equalsIgnoreCase(criteriaValue)){
                if (numberOfInputElements<1) {
                    **result = cells.get(searchHeaderIndex).getText();**
                    break;
                } else if (numberOfInputElements>0) {
                    **result = cells.get(searchHeaderIndex).findElement(By.xpath(".//input")).getAttribute("value");**
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```